# toggleHighlight to function correctly with HTML5 video and text

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use toggleHighlight in javascript to enable my text to highlight in sync with the audio from a HTML5 video.  Below is a sample of the code I am working with.  Can anyone see what steps I am missing in order to make this function correctly?  Thank you.

HTML5

```
<!--Video Subtitles --> 

    <div id="transcript">

            <p><span class="cue" data-start="0">Now that we've looked at the architecture of the internet, let's see how you might</span>
            <span class="cue" data-start="4.13">connect your personal devices to the internet inside your house. </span></p>
```

CSS

```
.highlighted {
    color: orange;
}
```

Javascript (sample)

```
video.addEventListener("timeupdate", highlightText, false);


// Text highlighting as the video is playing 

// Highlight transcript
function highlightText() {
    //Get current video time
    var highlightTime = video.currentTime;

        //Highlight span corresponding to current time
        function toggleHighlight(n) {
            // Removed highlight from any unclicked text
            for (var i = 0; i < cues.length; i++) {
                cues[i].classList.remove("highlighted");
            }
            //Add highlighted class
            cues[n].classList.add("highlighted");
        }

        if (highlightTime > 0 && highlightTime < 4.13) {
            toggleHighlight(0);
        } else if (highlightTime > 4.13 && highlightTime < 7.535) {
            toggleHighlight(1);
        }
```

Comment: what is `cues`? what is `video`? provide a complete working example...

Comment: I have put my code into here https://jsfiddle.net/TLXL/bh3ayjev/ unfortunately, my video is embedded, so it will not show up on here, but it might give you a better idea of what I am trying to do.  Thank you for your time.